# Use javascript/jquery to check form for element

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript

I am attempting to convert the VBScript on a page in an existing application to javascript.  Javascript does not have the function `Contains()` as VBScript does.  Is there an example of the `Contains()` function that would function the same way as VBScript?

```
<form method="post" runat="server" id="frmCrgEntry">

if(frmCrgEntry.Contains(frmCrgEntry.all("ddlHeaderAttdPhy"))) {
                if(document.frmCrgEntry.ddlHeaderAttdPhy.value === "0") {
                    AppendMsg(strFieldName + " is required.");
                }
            }
```

Comment: use `yourstring.indexOf('whatever') > -1`

Comment: IndexOf not index. and I see that you've edited your answer. there you go.

Comment: Should this be put into a separage Contains() function returning true/false or just use the indexOf() right in the if statement?

Comment: you can use it right inside the if statement.. if the word doesn't contain 'whatever' it will return -1 else it returns the index of 'whatever'

Comment: what is `ddlHeaderAttdPhy`? is it an element id

Comment: Yes, ddlHeaderAttdPhy is an element id.

Comment: is this server side javascript (jscript) or client side (in the browser)?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#ddlHeaderAttdPhy').val() === '0') { ... }
```

If the element with that ID does not exist, the statement will silently fail.

If the element with that ID does exist but it is a checkbox or select element, use `:checked` or `:selected` as necessary.

See http://api.jquery.com/val/ for more on `.val()`.

Comment: The question asks for a JavaScript/jQuery solution.

Answer (score 0):

1) Do you really need to check if the form contains the element? Are there any cases where it does not contain it?

2) You could try something like this

```
// check if the element exists in the form
if(document.frmCrgEntry.ddlHeaderAttdPhy) {
    // check if a value has been selected
    if(document.frmCrgEntry.ddlHeaderAttdPhy.value === "0") {
        AppendMsg(strFieldName + " is required.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get the question right, you can use `typeof` and do something like this:

```
<form id="frm">
    <div id="xyz">abc
        <input id="foo" type="text" />
    </div>
</form>

<script language="JavaScript">
    alert((typeof document.all.frm.all('xyz')) == 'object'); //true
    alert((typeof document.all.frm.all.xyz) == 'object');    //true
    alert((typeof document.all.frm.all('foo')) == 'object'); //true
    alert((typeof document.all.frm.all.foo) == 'object');    //true
</script>
```